# Need help Speech-to-text, always failed for too many retries

Tags: google-cloud-speech

I use google speech-to-text API to get subtitles from audio, but when audio is too long, normally longer than 60 minutes, it will fail for too many retries.It says: google.api_core.exceptions.GoogleAPICallError: None Too many retries, giving up.

Can someone help me ??

I have tried many time, when audio file is shorter than about 60 minutes, it is OK.

```
client = speech.SpeechClient()

# Loads audio into memory.
audio = types.RecognitionAudio(uri=gcs_uri)
config = types.RecognitionConfig(
    encoding=enums.RecognitionConfig.AudioEncoding.OGG_OPUS,
    sample_rate_hertz=48000,
    language_code='en-US',
    enable_word_time_offsets=True,
    enable_automatic_punctuation=True)

# Detects speech in the audio file
operation = client.long_running_recognize(config, audio)
print('Waiting for operation to complete...')
# Get the feedback from Google Cloud API
operation.add_done_callback(callback)
time.sleep(30)
#metadata = operation.metadata
# Every 30 seconds to get back one response
percentile(operation, 30)

response = operation.result(timeout=None)
```

Comment: take a look here: https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/async-recognize?hl=en

Comment: and here: https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/quotas

Comment: Could you please show the exact error thrown out @DLI42

Answer (score 1):

This is an exception thrown by operation.result() call. The operation.result() call has an internal counter that overflows.
Try to poll operation.done() before calling to operation.result(). The operation.done() is a non-blocking call.
Hope that will be fixed in future releases of google.cloud.speech library.